# shuf file --output file: in-place shuffling

Tags: text-processing, files, io-redirection, random, coreutils

The `shuf` command has an `--output` flag that you can use to specify where to write its output (instead of writing to stdout).

I want to shuffle a file in-place.  Is it safe to use `shuf file --output file`, using the same filename for the output filename and the file to read from?

Or could this cause file corruption?  Is it platform-specific?  It seems to work OK when I tested on a small file, but the man page doesn't say anything about this, and I'm not sure whether to worry about it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes - [per the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/shuf-invocation.html) - it should be safe to shuffle a file in-place:

> `-o output-file`
>   `--output=output-file`
>       Write output to *output-file* instead of standard output. `shuf` reads all input before opening *output-file*, so you can safely shuffle a file
>   in place by using commands like `shuf -o F <F` and `cat F | shuf -o F`.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, spot-testing on a small file seems to do what you want, but if you want to be safe, the best option would be to write to a temporary file and then swap the new one in:

```
#!/bin/bash
scratch=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm -f "$scratch"' EXIT
if [[ -r "$1" ]]; then
    shuf "$1" --output "$scratch" && mv "$scratch" "$1"
fi
```

The above script can be saved as e. g. `shuf_in_place` in your `PATH`.